# How to could get a React Native app Screen over phone locked?

Tags: react-native

Im trying to learn React Native my problem is run my app on android locked screen. How can i get my app screen  every time pushed phone lock button and getting my app screen over android lock screen

Comment: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/939

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OLmEzqnSfzU 
yes the application will work well when the phone is in sleep mode but also I want to get the application screen without unlocking  each screen when the screen is pressed

Comment: https://youtu.be/Z0TqYyxHCXc?t=59 like this

Comment: how did you fixed it?